# timedelta returning wrong month

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-datetime

I wrote some code to send requests to an API. The API allows the search to be performed between a given set of dates. My code takes a datetime object and increases that object by a timedelta, lets call this timedelta d. I have a second datetime object which increments the by d-1. The idea is to get non overlapping time periods. Everything seems to be working fine except that when the date changes from November the first back to October 31st, the month returned by my date time is incorrect. Here is the code:

```
start_date=datetime(2013,9,22)
end_date=datetime(2013,12,1)

d = start_date
delta = timedelta(days=10)

while d <= end_date:
    ys=d.strftime('%Y')
    ms=d.strftime('%m')
    ds=d.strftime('%d')
    d += delta

    ye=d.strftime('%Y')
    me=d.strftime('%m')
    de=(d-timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%d')
    print ys+'-'+ms+'-'+ds+'..'+ye+'-'+me+'-'+de
```

And here is the output:2013-09-22..2013-10-01

```
2013-10-02..2013-10-11
2013-10-12..2013-10-21
2013-10-22..2013-11-31 #the second date printed should be 2013-10-31
2013-11-01..2013-11-10
2013-11-11..2013-11-20
2013-11-21..2013-12-30
2013-12-01..2013-12-10
```

Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: Try using the *freeze_gun* library for unit testing so you can debug. Allows you to easily mock the current date/time

Comment: you are calculating the month for the first day of the next section but the day by subtracting one. try using `final_day = d-timedelta(days=1) ; ye=final_day.strftime("%Y")... `etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right I see my error now, after I subtract a day the whole time object change, but the month and year previously defined as string do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `d-timedelta(days=1)` on all the `ye`, `me` and `de`, not only `de`

Answer (score 1):

after you have executed:

```
d += delta
```

then `d` represents the start date of the next interval, in one case in your data that is `2013-11-01` so when you get the year and month of that data you get `2013-11` and then get the date of one day before which is `2013-10-31` so it gets `31` instead get all three fields from one day before:

```
end_interval=d-timedelta(days=1)
ye = end_interval.strftime('%Y')
me=end_interval.strftime('%m')
de=(end_interval).strftime('%d')
print(ys+'-'+ms+'-'+ds+'..'+ye+'-'+me+'-'+de)
```

or much more concisely you can use `strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` to get all three fields at once.

```
start_str = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
d += delta

end_str = (d-timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(start_str+'..'+end_str)
```

or even more concisely then that:

```
start_date=datetime(2013,9,22)
end_date=datetime(2013,12,1)

d = start_date
delta = timedelta(days=10)

interval = delta - timedelta(days=1) #the difference between the start of an interval and the last day

while d <= end_date:
    end = d+interval #last day of interval
    print("{:%Y-%m-%d}...{:%Y-%m-%d}".format(d, end))
    d = end + timedelta(days=1) #set d to one day more then the end of interval
```